# Build Cordova project and launch emulator with grunt task

Tags: cordova, gruntjs

I am rather new with cordova and grunt.

I was able to create a phonegap app through the cli:

```
cordova create test1 com.example.test1 Test1 
cd test1
cordova platform add android
cordova build android
```

Also with the genymotion emulator run through eclipse I am able to emulate the created app.

What I am trying to do is create a grunt task that builds the phonegap app and runs the emulator. I have never used grunt before so I googled and find this article:

http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/11/7/Using-Grunt-to-automatically-build-your-PhoneGapCordova-projects

and the snippet from it:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){

    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        exec:{
            prepare:{
                command:"cordova prepare",
                stdout:true,
                stderror:true
            }
        },
        watch:{
            files:['www/**/*.*'],
            tasks:['exec:prepare']
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```

As far as I understand this prepares the phonegap app when there is a change in the www folder.

Can anybody help me with some working example for my case and probably some explanation as I am very new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK.. there is a nice way you can handle this.

Install grunt-shell,

```
npm install --save-dev grunt-shell
```

Define the following in your Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
var path = require('path');
var cordova_cmd = function(cmd) {
     var target = grunt.option('target') || "ios";
     return path.join(
      __dirname, "platforms",
      target, "cordova", cmd);
     }

grunt.initConfig({
shell: {
        build: {
            command: 'cordova build && ' +
            cordova_cmd('emulate')
        },
        run: {
            command: 'cordova build &&' +
            cordova_cmd("run")
        }
    },
});
```

then register tasks to run those commands

```
grunt.registerTask('emulate', [
'shell:build']);

   grunt.registerTask('run', [
   'shell:run'
 ]);
```

This should allow you to run

```
>grunt emulate
```

to emulate or

```
>grunt run
```

to run on real device

Comment: Pretty helpful but feels a long winded way round I just want to be able to do it CLI fashion first from my ionic fw..
ionic run android is supposed to work...for the genymotion virtual device

Comment: Great, thanks for the inspiration.  I went with a slightly different approach: emulate_ios: {
                command: 'cd ' + cordova_root + ' && cordova build ios && cordova emulate ios'
            }

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try [this](https://www.npmjs.org/package/generator-phonegap) , it generates full project with nice structure and already has the build scripts ready